# specifying database on select statement is not working in MySQL View

Tags: mysql, phpactiverecord

```
 SELECT `db_name`.`view_name` . *
 FROM `db_name`.`view_name`
```

Above query statement for View is not working.
Below error occurred.

```
#1051 - Unknown table 'view_name'
```

Below query statements for Table is working. (same)

```
 SELECT `db_name`.`table_name` . *
 FROM `db_name`.`table_name`

 SELECT *
 FROM `db_name`.`view_name`
```

I don't know why this work. 
Could you tell me why this happened? (or some link)

Thank you.

MySQL version is 5.1.73.

Comment: Did you missed `schemaname` ? Is the `db_name` is the actual database name ?

Comment: There is a `.` (dot) before the `*` symbol - typo??

Comment: I'm edited my question.

Comment: @Arulkumar Yes, It is the actual database name.

Comment: @DawidSATokyo Yes, It is `.` (dot).

Comment: @Arulkumar Ah, I missed `schemaname`. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
SELECT * FROM `db_name`.`table_name`;
You don't need to put DB and Table name after the SELECT. You could do something like this to select particular column:
SELECT `column1`,`column2` FROM `db_name`.`table_name`

Comment: It is work. But the problem is above statement is generated by ORM named PhpActiveRecord.

Comment: Because  I need know why not woking to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you missed the `schemaname` in the select statement

So your query will be

```
SELECT `dbname`.`schemaname`.`tablename`.*
FROM `dbname`.`schemaname`.`tablename`
```

or simply `*` in the SELECT as

```
SELECT *
FROM `dbname`.`schemaname`.`tablename`
```

Comment: Yes. For example: If you are fetching data from any linked server table, in this case you need to call the other database table in this way. But with in same database: schemaname.tablename is enough